# Current and voltage complex diagram for a transformer

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, diagram

I was wondering how would a complex diagram for current and voltage look both for an ideal transformer and for a fully coupled lossless transformer. The diagram for a coil looks like this:

[image]

The ideal transformer looks like this and the current and voltage are:
[image]

The fully coupled lossless transformer:

[image]

So all and all I'm looking for two diagrams, one for the ideal and one for the fully coupled lossless transformer that contain both currents and both voltages on it. I think that the diagram for ideal transformer is supposed to look like this, but I'm not sure:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what an ideal transformer is?

Comment: Fully-coupled and lossless = ideal. What is your real question?

Comment: U1 and U2 are in phase (no angle between them). Same for I1 and I2.

Comment: @StefanWyss Does it look like [this](https://imgur.com/XQVZXjT) then?

Comment: Yes, I think this is pretty much how it looks.